# Limits of integration for change of variables in multivariable calculus

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals

> $$
> \int_0^1 \int_0^1 x^2y \, dx \, dy
> $$

let $u = x$ and $v = xy$

Jacobian determinant
$\Bigl|\frac{\partial(u,v)}{\partial (x,y)}\Bigr| = x$ hence:
$$
du\,dv = x\,dx\,dy
$$
and
$$
\iint v \,du\,dv
$$

My problems are the limit of integration how can I find them?

Comment: Why do you want to change variables on a function that is easily integrable in the starting coordinates? You can find the new bounds by plugging the old ones into the change of variables.

Comment: @NinadMunshi to practice change of variables

Comment: So clearly you should do $\iint \,dv\,du$, and $0\le u\le 1$. For $u$ fixed, $0\le y=\frac vu\le 1$, so what are the limits on $v$?

Answer (score 2):

If $x$ goes from $0$ to $1$, $u$ goes from $0$ to $1$ as well since $x=u$.

If $y$ goes from $0$ to $1$, $v$ has to go from $x\cdot 0$ to $x\cdot 1$ since $v=x\cdot y$.

Your integral becomes

$$\int_0^1\int_0^xv\;\mathrm{d}v\;\mathrm{d}u.$$

This is not completely correct yet, since $v$ depends on $x$. So now we use $u=x$ to get

$$\int_0^1\int_0^uv\;\mathrm{d}v\;\mathrm{d}u.$$

Note that now the integration order matters since the inner integral is a function of the outer $v$.

I don't understand why you would do this kind of substitution. Why would you introduce dependencies of variables? It will most definitely not make your integral easier...

Comment: seems like there is a typo on the limits of u book answer says: $\int_v^1$? taking dudv

Comment: The big problem with your substitution is that it is the same as: $u=x$ and $v=uy$, meaning $v$ depends on $u$. It is a bad substitution, that I would recommend staying away from.

Comment: @SirMrpirateroberts let me check if I made a mistake real quick

Comment: I think is because the book is taking dudv du first

Comment: @SirMrpirateroberts My solution is correct, the result of both integrals is $\frac{1}{6}$

Comment: What is the full solution of your book?

Comment: $$\int_0^1 \int_v^1 vdudv$$

Comment: No clue how they got that, seems more logical to do $\mathrm{d}v$ first. Seems like a bad exercice to me with a weird solution that somehow works. Again I heavily recommend to stay away from that kind of substitutions.

Comment: @VincentBatens "no clue how they got that" ? That very concerns me, as this is the simplest example of reversing integration order that most people in multivariate calculus classes learn and you are unable to see it, instead telling OP to not learn and not try.

Comment: @NinadMunshi I didn't express myself right, I meant that I have no clue why they went with this order of variables, it feels like overcomplicating stuff for no reason. There is no reason to then switch the order of the integrals.

Comment: I don't see how to get there directly, maybe I'm not used enough to integrals anymore. To get from my integral to yours @SirMrpirateroberts you can draw the area you integrate over in the $u,v$-plane and see between what values $u$ has to be for a fixed $v$, you can just let $v$ go from $0$ to $1$ and for every fixed $v$, $u$ has to be between $v$ and $1$. (You get a triangle) I don't think this really answers your question though.

Answer (score 1):

You want to **invert** the change-of-variables relations so that the *old* coordinates $(x, y)$ are expressed in terms of the *new* coordinates $(u, v)$:
$$
\begin{cases}
x = u \\[2pt]
\displaystyle y = \frac vu
\end{cases}
$$
Now, we want to calculate the Jacobian of *this* transformation:
$$
\frac{\partial(x, y)}{\partial(u, v)} = 
\begin{vmatrix}
1 & 0 \\ 
-\frac{v}{u^2} & \frac1u
\end{vmatrix} 
= \frac1u
$$
(You can see that this is the reciprocal of your Jacobian $x = u$.)

Putting this together, the entire differentials transform as:
$$
x^2 y \, dx \, dy = 
u^2 \cdot \frac vu \cdot \frac1u \, dv \, du = 
v \, dv \, du
$$

Now, for **bounds:** $0 \leq x \leq 1$ becomes $0 \leq u \leq 1$. Now, $0 \leq y \leq 1$ becomes $0 \leq \smash{\frac vu} \leq 1$, or $0 \leq v \leq u$. Since, the variable $v$ is bounded by a nonconstant function of $u$, we must integrate with respect to $v$ first:
$$
\int_0^1 \int_0^1 x^2 y \, dx \, dy = 
\int_0^1 \int_0^u v \, dv \, du, 
$$
which yields the same value as if you had integrated in the original variables. (I leave it to you.)

$^*$This calculation isn't entirely rigorous, as the the change of variables introduces a singularity: $y \to \infty$ as $u \to 0$, but it turns out not to matter. Change-of-variables transformations are meant to be diffeomorphisms on the interiors of regions, i.e. open sets anyway, but I digress.

Comment: While your answer is correct, OP's approach is wiser than you give it credit for. Most of the time, finding the inverse Jacobian is much easier than finding the forward Jacobian, and they are related by the simple $J^{-1} = 1/J$ as you discovered after much extra work. I always advocate for not inverting the relationships if not necessary.